Bluetooth streaming interferes with Android controller for Phonak hearing aids in Ubuntu 24.04; Hardware works in Windows 10
Thus far my research has only found information about pairing.  I'm not having difficulty pairing.
I have new Phonak hearing aids.  They have Android software that can control aspects of the hearing aids functionality.  (Volume, balance, equalizer, etc.)  I am able to pair the devices with a USB Bluetooth dongle in both Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 10.  It is a dual boot computer.  I am able to stream audio from both operating systems.  In Windows the Android controller can still communicate with the hearing aids during streaming.  In Linux, streaming works but the connection to the controller is lost.  The connection to the controller recovers after terminating the streaming.
Of note -- pairing the Android with the hearing aids involved pairing twice; one for the controller connection and another for the streaming media connection.  I mention this because it is different than a simple BT headset pairing.
I wonder if the BT device is somehow being "greedy" with radio frequencies when I'm using Linux.  If my guess is correct, I wonder if this could be a "corner case" driver issue.
